# Complete freeze without log after some time

Tags: linux, freeze

I have a computer which keeps freezing after some time. It boots up and runs seemingly without problems, but after a while, especially with some load, it ends up freezing completely. There is still a still image on the screen, and a buggy sound coming out of the headphones, but I can't move the pointer or interact with anything (even with keyboard).

Here are its specs:

- CPU: AMD FX-8350
- Motherboard: Gigabyte 990FXA-UD3
- RAM: two 8GB and one 1GB RAM modules (showing no error on the BIOS memory test)
- Graphic card: Nvidia GeForce GTX 750 Ti

It has a Xubuntu 23.10 with Linux 6.5.0-10-generic.
I always had problems with XHCI and USB3 with this motherboard, so some messages appear about this in journalctl, but except this, I see absolutely no useful logs about crashes.
Also, it is plugged in a UPS so I guess it can't be a power input problem...

Here are the last lines of the journalctl just before the last hard-reboot I did, when it froze at around 13:49 PM today.

```
nov. 04 13:43:27 mmarx xdg-desktop-por[2570]: No skeleton to export
nov. 04 13:43:27 mmarx xdg-desktop-por[2570]: Choosing gtk.portal for org.freedesktop.impl.portal.FileChooser via temporary hard-coded fallback
nov. 04 13:43:27 mmarx xdg-desktop-por[2570]: Choosing gtk.portal for org.freedesktop.impl.portal.AppChooser via temporary hard-coded fallback
nov. 04 13:43:27 mmarx xdg-desktop-por[2570]: Choosing gtk.portal for org.freedesktop.impl.portal.Print via temporary hard-coded fallback
nov. 04 13:43:27 mmarx xdg-desktop-por[2570]: Choosing gtk.portal for org.freedesktop.impl.portal.Notification via temporary hard-coded fallback
nov. 04 13:43:27 mmarx xdg-desktop-por[2570]: Choosing gtk.portal for org.freedesktop.impl.portal.Inhibit via temporary hard-coded fallback
nov. 04 13:43:27 mmarx xdg-desktop-por[2570]: Choosing gtk.portal for org.freedesktop.impl.portal.Access via temporary hard-coded fallback
nov. 04 13:43:27 mmarx xdg-desktop-por[2570]: Choosing gtk.portal for org.freedesktop.impl.portal.Account via temporary hard-coded fallback
nov. 04 13:43:27 mmarx xdg-desktop-por[2570]: Choosing gtk.portal for org.freedesktop.impl.portal.Email via temporary hard-coded fallback
nov. 04 13:43:27 mmarx xdg-desktop-por[2570]: Choosing gtk.portal for org.freedesktop.impl.portal.DynamicLauncher via temporary hard-coded fallback
nov. 04 13:43:27 mmarx dbus-daemon[1125]: [session uid=1000 pid=1125] Successfully activated service 'org.freedesktop.portal.Desktop'
nov. 04 13:43:27 mmarx systemd[1101]: Started xdg-desktop-portal.service - Portal service.
nov. 04 13:43:28 mmarx rtkit-daemon[1139]: Successfully made thread 2666 of process 2564 owned by '1000' high priority at nice level -10.
nov. 04 13:43:28 mmarx rtkit-daemon[1139]: Supervising 8 threads of 5 processes of 1 users.
nov. 04 13:43:28 mmarx rtkit-daemon[1139]: Successfully made thread 2667 of process 2564 owned by '1000' high priority at nice level -10.
nov. 04 13:43:28 mmarx rtkit-daemon[1139]: Supervising 9 threads of 5 processes of 1 users.
nov. 04 13:43:28 mmarx rtkit-daemon[1139]: Successfully made thread 2687 of process 2564 owned by '1000' high priority at nice level -10.
nov. 04 13:43:28 mmarx rtkit-daemon[1139]: Supervising 10 threads of 5 processes of 1 users.
nov. 04 13:43:40 mmarx rtkit-daemon[1139]: Successfully made thread 2870 of process 2848 owned by '1000' high priority at nice level -15.
nov. 04 13:43:40 mmarx rtkit-daemon[1139]: Supervising 11 threads of 6 processes of 1 users.
nov. 04 13:45:09 mmarx rtkit-daemon[1139]: Successfully made thread 2940 of process 2848 owned by '1000' high priority at nice level -15.
nov. 04 13:45:09 mmarx rtkit-daemon[1139]: Supervising 11 threads of 6 processes of 1 users.
nov. 04 13:52:41 mmarx dbus-daemon[1125]: [session uid=1000 pid=1125] Activating service name='org.xfce.Xfconf' requested by ':1.23' (uid=1000 pid=1427 comm="xfce4-panel" label="unconfined")
nov. 04 13:52:41 mmarx dbus-daemon[1125]: [session uid=1000 pid=1125] Successfully activated service 'org.xfce.Xfconf'
```

I also see this line appearing frequently but IDK if it may be related to this: `nov. 04 13:02:46 mmarx kernel: [drm:nv_drm_master_set [nvidia_drm]] *ERROR* [nvidia-drm] [GPU ID 0x00000100] Failed to grab modeset ownership`

The problem still appears after a complete reinstall of the system, so I feel this may be a hardware problem, but don't quite know how to diagnose it with so little info (and I'm quite a beginner with sysadmin etc)... Would you have any advice about this? I can post the output of other commands if needed. Thank you in advance!

Comment: does your keyboard have a numlock light that goes on/off when you press the button? if so, can your numlock state change while it is frozen?

Comment: Well, I tried to reproduce the problem but this time it just rebooted instantly (with still not a log in journalctl). But, from memory, I think the numlock button does nothing and the LED remains fixed. I'll try again tomorrow to confirm (sorry for the delay).